# Is there an easier way to format this data for SQL

Tags: sql, data-cleaning

I am trying to format this dataset so that it is easier to use when I do SQL on it. Is there an easier way besides combining and changing all the columns into a single column so that I can call it easier using SELECT functions? For example, I would like to be able to have all the diseases under one "disease" column. When dealing with large sets of data, I can't afford to copy and paste to rearrange the data

eg:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the data, but the structure looks fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by combining all the diseases into one column, but it sounds like it might violate DB normalization rules (in this case the first normal form). Consider [reading into it](https://www.w3schools.in/DBMS/database-normalization/) if you're unsure what that means.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to `UNPIVOT` this data set

Comment: How many columns are there? You can do this by using self joins as well

Comment: What RDBMS please?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few techniques you can use to do this, effectively you want to `UNPIVOT` the columns into rows.

MS SQL UNPIVOT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39bc16/2

```
SELECT [Entity],[Code],[Year],[Disease],[Rate]
FROM [Results]
UNPIVOT ([Rate] FOR [Disease] 
          IN ([Cardiovascular],[Neoplasm],[Respiratory],[Diabetes],[Alzheimers]) 
) AS [ResultsSource]
```

| Entity | Code | Year | Disease | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1990 | Cardiovascular | 23.70775 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1990 | Neoplasm | 5.129907 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1990 | Respiratory | 3.036222 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1990 | Diabetes | 3.832555 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1990 | Alzheimers | 0.999691 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1991 | Cardiovascular | 23.49031 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1991 | Neoplasm | 5.086501 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1991 | Respiratory | 3.012502 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1991 | Diabetes | 3.822228 |
| Afganistan | AFG | 1991 | Alzheimers | 0.994872 |

> In a normalised database the `Entity` and `Disease` would be defined in their own tables, and linked via FKs. The code would normally be associated in the `Entity` table.

Not all databases provide an `UNPIVOT` function, as explained in [this article](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/unpivot-in-sql/) there are some other ways to generate the same result set, for a small number of columns, a simple `UNION ALL` can do the same thing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39bc16/4

```
SELECT [Entity],[Code],[Year],'Cardiovascular' as [Disease], [Cardiovascular] as [Rate]
FROM [Results]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity],[Code],[Year],'Neoplasm' as [Disease], [Neoplasm] as [Rate]
FROM [Results]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity],[Code],[Year],'Respiratory' as [Disease], [Respiratory] as [Rate]
FROM [Results]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity],[Code],[Year],'Diabetes' as [Disease], [Diabetes] as [Rate]
FROM [Results]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Entity],[Code],[Year],'Alzheimers' as [Disease], [Alzheimers] as [Rate]
FROM [Results]
```

---

For an example of how to use this output to store into a normalised structure please review this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66eba/2

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (...)
SELECT ..., disease_val_col1 FROM old_table UNION
SELECT ..., disease_val_col2 FROM old_table UNION
...
;
```

to populate a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
    id       int primary key auto_increment
  , region   int
  , year     int
  , disease  int
  , curval   decimal(9, 7)
  , code     VARCHAR(30)
  , foreign key (disease) references disease(id)
  , foreign key (region)  references regions(id)
  , foreign key (code)    references codes(code)
);
```

along with the other tables for region, codes, disease, etc.
There's a little more to do to obtain the associated primary key values to use in the stats table.

Review concepts like "database normalization" for more detail on ways to design / structure your tables.